# FileReader scope issue in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, closures

I'm having trouble figuring out how to access `this` in the `render.onload` function below. I know the answer probably involves closures, but I can't quite wrap my mind around it yet.

```
var PhotoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.uploadPhoto();
  },

  uploadPhoto: function() {
    var file = this.get("file");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      // I don't have access to "this" here...
      this.dataURL = event.target.result;
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: You do have access to `this` but it's no longer a reference to the same object. In the inner function, `this` is `reader`. Try assigning eg `var model = this.model` in the outer scope, then `model.dataURL = ...` in the inner scope. Thus, you exploit the closure that is already formed. No need to form another one.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a reference to `this` outside the scope of that function like this:

```
var self = this; // or var that = this;
reader.onload = function() {
    // access `this` using `self`
    self.model.dataURL = event.target.result;
}
```